# How to query by labels in neo4j using Java core API

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

I wondered if anyone knows how to query nodes in neo4j by label using QueryContext?  For example to do something like this:

```
QueryContext queryCtx = new QueryContext("Label:Confirmed");
Index<Node> idx = indexManaged.indexFor("users");
IndexHits<Node> userNodes = idx.query(queryCtx).sort(sortByName).top(10));
```

Many thanks!

Also if the guys at Neo are reading, your docs are down at the following links:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html
and
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/rest-api-schema-indexes.html